# SharePoint Column Conditional Formatting - Applying CSS classes to a date field using a nested IF statement

Tags: list, date-time, json-formatting, column-formatting, if-condition

Apologies, I am relatively new to SharePoint/JSON, So forgive me if I am not seeing the obvious. I would be INCREDIBLY grateful if someone would help.

I would like to apply conditional formatting to a **date** field using a nested IF statement.

*IF the current field is blank, then set the CSS class to 'blocked'. However, if the current field is populated, run a second IF: IF the current field is more than 1 year before today, then set the CSS class to 'blocked', however if the current field is within the last year, set the CSS class to 'good'.*

I have ran the following, without success. No formatting is applied whatsoever.

```
{

  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",

"elmType": "div",

"attributes": {

"class": "=if(toString(@currentField)=='', 'sp-field-severity--blocked', if([@currentField]+31104000000 < @now,'sp-field-severity--blocked', 'sp-field-severity--good'))"
  },

"txtContent": "@currentField"

}
```

HOWEVER, when I split the conditions into two, they work independently.

1. =IF empty, blocked, good.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(toString(@currentField)=='','sp-field-severity--blocked', 'sp-field-severity--good')"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

2. =IF exceeds 1 year, blocked, good.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField+31104000000 < @now, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', 'sp-field-severity--good')"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

My next step would be to add the corresponding CSS class icon into the field.

Comment: Are you trying to format the row or just the date field?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Hi, I am only trying to format the date field, not the row. Thanks.

Comment: I would massively appreciate some direction on this, @GaneshSanap or others. I have been stuck for 3 days.. I'm certain that the solution is something very straightforward, which I have missed.

Comment: I have tried the same you are trying to achieve and the result is same. I don't understand why it is not working after merging both conditions.

Comment: It is working fine for second condition. But, it is not working for blank/empty fields after merging both codes.

Comment: Yes, it is very strange. Thanks for trying @GaneshSanap

Comment: Also I tried by removing condition of empty field and adding another conditions which will fulfill your requirements but result was same. I guess we are adding milliseconds in the value which is causing this issue as date field always stores default value even when we leave it as blank in list form.